# Helicoil-Screw Torque Spec

Tags: materials

My project incorporates the use of various metals and plastics to include ABS, G10, aluminum, titanium, and brass, and we drill and helicoil all mounting screw holes. I'm having a bit of difficulty locating a proper torque spec chart for the screws tightening into these various conditions. Does anyone have a good resource?

Comment: Plastics tend to vary a lot but if you can find their structural specs, you can do a simplified approximation of how much shear a cylinder of your insert diameter and depth would be pulled out being turned and (more importantly) pulled by your screw.  That will get you a max limit.